# Why does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$ diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$$

I tried by comparing it to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ but i seem to fail.

I think I need to compare with series that are smaller and diverge. Help.

Comment: Use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

Comment: are you sure it diverges? because as per the ration method if you compute, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{log(n+1)!}}{\frac{1}{log(n)!}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{log(n+1)}=0$.

Comment: I have solutions in my book and the solution is : D which means divergence

Comment: The series isn't defined if $n=0$ and $n=1$

Comment: Logarithms grow as slowly as exponentials increase. The factorial function grows faster than any given exponential, so the $ln(n!)$ grows faster than $ln(e^n) = n$ (which also diverges).

Comment: @JohnCramerus If you have $\ln (n!)\geq \ln (e^n)=n$ it implies that $1/ \ln (n!) \leq 1/n$ but that does **not** help to conclude to the divergence of the given series.

Comment: Youre right, my bad

Answer (score 16):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
n! \leq n^n,\quad n\geq2,
$$ giving
$$
\ln(n!) \leq \ln(n^n)=n\ln n
$$ and, for $N\geq2$,

> $$
> \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln(n!)} \geq \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\ln n}
> $$

then let $N \to \infty$ to conclude.

Comment: Beat me to it +1.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi Thank you very much.

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n\ln n}$ diverges by integral criterium right?

Comment: @RushThaMan Exactly or using the Cauchy condensation test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).